How to infer a generic type parameter from another in Java?
I'm using a class that uses two generic type parameters in Java, but I find the second type parameter to be redundant because it is already determined by the first.
Here’s the current class declaration:
public abstract class GameScreen<C extends Controller<G>, G extends Game> extends MPScreen {
    public G getGameInstance() {
        // ...
    }
    public C getController() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

Controller is a generic type that takes a Game type, like so:
public abstract class Controller<G extends Game> {
    // ...
}

I would like to avoid having to specify the second type parameter (G) directly because it's already determined by C. However, I still want to use G as the return type in some methods (like getGameInstance()).
I tried to rewrite the class like this:
public abstract class GameScreen<C extends Controller<? extends Game>> extends MPScreen {
    public C getController() {
        // ...
    }
}

But with this approach, I lose access to G as a distinct type, so I can't use it as a return type in methods like getGameInstance().
My question is:
Is there a way in Java to infer the type parameter G from the type C without explicitly declaring G as a second type parameter? Or is there a cleaner way to achieve this while still having G as a method return type?

In Java Generica infor is available only at compile time. At runtime these all Object.

No, I don't believe what you want is possible. Not if you want to maintain type safety (the solution in sarwar's answer can easily lead to a ClassCastException). Note the G in your example may not be necessary to parameterize the type argument of C (as you've shown, you could just use a wildcard), but that doesn't mean the G is redundant. Its purpose is to declare a type that can be used in the scope of GameScreen. Without it, which symbol would you use as the return type of getGameInstance()? It'd only be redundant if you didn't use G elsewhere in the class (but you do).

@Slaw I would think that I'd be able to say something like GameScreen<C extends Controller<G extends Game>> but this leads to an error.
I don't see anything wrong with this idea, so maybe Java just doesn't support it since it's not a common enough issue? Either that or I'm missing some issue with supporting that kind of parameter

If you want to use G in GameScreen you have to declare it, there is no other way.
But if your issue is that you have a lot of GameScreen implementations for the same Game, you can create a dedicated subclass of GameScreen specifically for that Game where only the Controller needs to be specified.
Suppose MyGame extends Game, you could have:
class MyGameScreen<C extends Controller<MyGame>> extends GameScreen<C, MyGame>

It will inherit these two methods from GameScreen, which could be overridden if necessary:
    public MyGame getGameInstance()

    public C getController()


Why not just use G as a type parameter?
public abstract class GameScreen<G extends Game> extends MPScreen {
    public G getGameInstance() {
        // ...
    }
    public Controller<G> getController() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}


because I need something that extends Controller specifically, that may have it's own fields and methods

That makes no sense. You cant reach more derived type's fields inside GameScreen class. Even with the first version of your code.

I can... For example I have a class SolitaireController extends Controller<SolitaireGame> (with additional fields/methods)
Theoretically GameScreen<SolitaireController> should be enough information to fulfill both type parameters but it seems that java doesn't have support for that, so I have to type GameScreen<SolitaireController, SolitaireGame> (Even though I can make it so that the second type parameter has to match the first, which I do in my original example)

You cannot reach SolitaireController fields inside GameScreen with a type parameter given that C extends Controller<G> on GameScreen. You can only reach the fields of base class in other words the fields of Controller<G>

not inside GameScreen itself, but inside something extending GameScreen I absolutely can

You want to avoid explicitly passing the G type parameter at the GameScreen level while still being able to use it as a return type in methods like getGameInstance().
You can reintroduce the G type parameter at the method level (instead of the class level), so it's inferred from the Controller.
Keep C as the Only Type Parameter and Infer G
public abstract class GameScreen<C extends Controller<? extends Game>> extends MPScreen {

    public C getController() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <G extends Game> G getGameInstance() {
        return (G) getController().getGame();
    }
}


getGameInstance() uses a method-level generic declaration (<G extends Game>). This allows the method to infer the specific type G from the controller when it’s called, without needing to declare G as a class-level type parameter.
The cast ensures that the controller's game type is correctly inferred as G.

Ensure Controller Provides the Concrete G
Make sure the Controller class defines a method that returns the specific G type:
public abstract class Controller<G extends Game> {
    public abstract G getGame();
}

By having Controller return the specific Game type (G), the method in GameScreen can safely cast the result to the correct type G.
